# AppCenter unable to distinct between multiple flutter(android) apps in same repository

Tags: android, flutter, appcenter

I'm trying to make CD-pipelines in AppCenter for 3 different flutter apps, contained within the same repository.

The issue is with the android applications. I've been following: https://buildflutter.com/deploying-flutter-apps-via-appcenter/ to make the applications visible to AppCenter. The problem occurs when trying to specify which android module, as AppCenter is not able to [distinct between the different modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCtVz.png) .

Comment: Is the repository on github?

Comment: @JunaidKhalid Yes it is.